# how to write custom sonar rule unsing pmd for java

Tags: sonarqube

I want to write custom sonar using Xpath query in PMD tool for java code.

Is there any different way to write custom sonar rule?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of Sonarqube and PMD plugin.

You can find an old example in [`SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pmd` issue 27](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pmd/issues/27#issuecomment-283110383), but with a more recent version 2.6, custom rules might not be supported anymore.